# Same width of the selection frame on elements of nested lists

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I need to make selection frame width of all nested ul li elements the same, like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0V9r.png),

i.e. so when hover over element (the whole line should be clickable) there would be no space on the left. I use AngularJS recursive directive to make this list (the depth can vary).

[Here's what I've got now](https://jsfiddle.net/Shushuka/dat9cfnn/2/) and so far cannot find the answer.

My CSS:

```
div[data-tree-model] li span:hover {
   background-color: #D7D7D7;
   border: 1px solid #A2A3A6;
   display: block; 
}

div[data-angular-treeview] {
   /* prevent user selection */
   -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
   /* default */
   font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size:13px;
   color: #2E9BDB;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-weight: bold;
}
div[data-tree-model] ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   overflow: hidden;

}
div[data-tree-model] li {
   position: relative;
   padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
div[data-tree-model] li span {
   cursor: pointer;
   white-space: nowrap;
   border: 1px solid transparent;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Directive template:

```
//tree template
var template =
    '<ul>' +
       '<li data-ng-repeat="node in ' + treeModel + '">' +
          '<span href="#" data-ng-class="{\'selected\': node.selected == true , \'collapsed\': node.' + nodeChildren + '.length && node.collapsed, \'expanded\': node.' + nodeChildren + '.length && !node.collapsed, \'folder\': node.' + nodeChildren + '.length}" data-ng-click="' + treeId + '.selectNodeLabel(node)" title={{node.' + nodeLabel + '}}>{{node.' + nodeLabel + '}}</span>' +
          '<div data-ng-hide="node.collapsed" data-tree-id="' + treeId + '" data-tree-model="node.' + nodeChildren + '" data-node-id=' + nodeId + ' data-node-label=' + nodeLabel + ' data-node-children=' + nodeChildren + '></div>' +
        '</li>' +
     '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If tree view is going to remain 3 level deep. Then we can do it [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhagya/f7vprng7/1/).
In your CSS you need to remove padding from below :

```
div[data-tree-model] li {
    position: relative;
   //padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

And need to add this CSS :

```
div[data-angular-treeview] > ul > li > span {
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
div[data-angular-treeview] > ul > li > div > ul > li > span {
  padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}
div[data-angular-treeview] > ul > li > div > ul > li > div > ul > li > span {
  padding: 0 0 0 60px;
}
div[data-angular-treeview] > ul > li > div > ul > li > div > ul > li > div > ul > li > span {
  padding: 0 0 0 80px;
}
```

This solution is for 3 level deep tree for current HTML DOM that is created through your directive. :)

Comment: Thank you, and do you have any thoughts, if the tree has random depth?